# How to make my tests pending in Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I want to make some of my `jest` tests pending. How can I do it? [API reference](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html) doesn't have any method how can I make my test pending.

Answer (score 32):

You can also just say

```
test.todo('Some test I still need to do')
```

The test runner will then have show a count of tests in a `todo` state:

```
Tests:       1 todo, 2 passed, 3 total
```

Comment: Note this is only available in Jest 24+

Comment: Now with jest v24 this should be the accepted answer. Marking a test as skipped is not quite the same as stating it is pending.

Answer (score 22):

**UPDATED**

Since jest@24.0.0 it's now possible to use:

```
it.todo(...)
test.todo(...)
```

Which will look like:

```
Tests:       1 todo, 23 passed, 24 total
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Setting tests as *Pending* per se is not featured in Jest.

However it allows to skip tests by using

```
it.skip(...)
test.skip(...)
```

And then they are marked not as passed but **skipped**:

```
Tests:       1 skipped, 23 passed, 24 total
```

Which for me is a very good equivalent to "pending".

Source [Skip one test in test file Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125230/skip-one-test-in-test-file-jest) by [Gleichmut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649629/gleichmut).

Comment: NOTE: `it.todo` and `test.todo` will still run `beforeAll` callbacks, even if the test file doesn't contain any active tests. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11006

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for `xit` and `xdescribe`

http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Disabling_Specs_and_Suites

Comment: `xit` and `xdescribe` just make tests passing. Can I show them as pending?

Comment: @asiniy I believe not as [pending](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs) is only available after jasmine 2.0, and jest uses 1.3

Answer (score 6):

Instead of saying `test(...)`, just say **xtest(...)** and the test will be skipped.

Comment: Is there a way to add reason which will show up in report? Like in Jasmine: xit().pend('Reason')

Comment: This won't make the test pending but it simply will make it pass.

Comment: Actually, it won't make the test pass, it will skip the test entirely. It will be not pending, not failed and not even passed.

Comment: I thought that was specific to mocha...?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the latest version of jest `xit` and `xdescribe` will show up as skipped for the default reporter.

If you really need to display pending specs you will need to create a custom reporter.

Here is the [link](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#reporters-array-modulename-modulename-options) to the jest documentation for setting a custom handler.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.