# Skip one test in test file Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest framework and have a test suite. I want to turn off/skip one of my tests.

Googling documentation doesn't give me answers.

Do you know the answer or source of information to check?

Comment: Just commenting it out?

Comment: It is not right way to deal test you want to skip by intent. At least such behavior doesn't pass software quality check in our team. (though I have one example of commented test in legacy code)

Comment: For anyone wanting to programmatically skip tests: Jest devs are unfortunately a bit stubborn about this and don't see the value of such an incredibly useful feature. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8604 and https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7245

Answer (score 254, accepted):

I found the answer here

https://devhints.io/jest

```
test('it is raining', () => {
  expect(inchesOfRain()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});

test.skip('it is not snowing', () => {
  expect(inchesOfSnow()).toBe(0);
});
```

[Link on off doc](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testskipname-fn)

Comment: ...and `test.only()`

Comment: describe.skip() for tests suits

Comment: it simply doesnt work with `yarn test`, jest is very annoying

Comment: with yarn tests, I use it.skip('my test', () => {/* my broken test code here*/})

Answer (score 102):

You can also exclude `test` or `describe` by prefixing them with an `x`.

**Individual Tests**

```
describe('All Test in this describe will be run', () => {
  xtest('Except this test- This test will not be run', () => {
   expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
  test('This test will be run', () => {
   expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

**Multiple tests inside a describe**

```
xdescribe('All tests in this describe will be skipped', () => {
 test('This test will be skipped', () => {
   expect(true).toBe(true);
 });

 test('This test will be skipped', () => {
   expect(true).toBe(true);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 73):

#### Skip a test

If you'd like to skip a test in Jest, you can use [test.skip](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api.html#testskipname-fn):

```
test.skip(name, fn)
```

Which is also under the following aliases:

- `it.skip(name, fn)` or
- `xit(name, fn)` or
- `xtest(name, fn)`

#### Skip a test suite

Additionally, if you'd like to skip a test suite, you can use [describe.skip](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describeskipname-fn):

```
describe.skip(name, fn)
```

Which is also under the following alias:

- `xdescribe(name, fn)`

Answer (score 13):

I would add this answer for the people that may fall here. As i was searching myself.

[only, skip, aliases (more details), doc refs, different variants (each, concurrent, failing), **how to ignore test files** (last section)]

You can skim. To get the sections.

## Skipping or running only one from within a file

### skip() [doc refs are included]

Use `.skip()` function to **skip** a **test** or a **test suite** (describe)

```
test('something', () => {})
```

=>

```
test.skip('something', () => {})
```

You can use aliases:

```
xtest('something', () => {})
```

The same applies to `it` which is an alias as well.

```
it.skip('something', () => {})
xit('something', () => {})
```

For a `descripe`:

```
describe.skip(() => {})
xdescribe(() => {})
```

doc refs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipname-fn
https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeskipname-fn

Aliases are to be found under the element title:

[image]

You can also test when @types/jest is installed through your editor:

[image]

`ftest` doesn't exit for example. See the next `only()` section.

**To note:**

```
test.skip.each(table)(name, fn)
```

For Data driven tests. Same aliases apply as well. Check the ref bellow.

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipeachtablename-fn

Same with:

```
test.concurrent.skip.each(table)(name, fn)
```

for concurrent tests. No x alias for this one. Check the ref bellow.

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testconcurrentskipeachtablename-fn

And,

```
describe.skip.each(table)(name, fn)
```

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeskipeachtablename-fn

```
test.skip.failing(name, fn, timeout)
```

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipfailingname-fn-timeout

### only()

Use `only()` if you want to run only that test and nothing else.

You can use `only()` with multiple tests or test suites (describe). That would run only the one that have `only()` added to them

> Note: only will act only at the file level. And not cross all files.

```
test('test 1', () => {})
test('test 2', () => {})
test('test 3', () => {})
test.only('test 4', () => {}) // only this would run in this file
```

multiple ones:

```
test('test 1', () => {})
test.only('test 2', () => {}) // only this
test('test 3', () => {})
test.only('test 4', () => {}) // and this would run in this file
```

With describe:

```
describe(() => {
   test('test 1', () => {})       // nothing will run here
   test.only('test 2', () => {}) // 
})

describe.only(() => {
   test('test 1', () => {})
   test.only('test 2', () => {}) // only this test
   test('test 3', () => {})
   test.only('test 4', () => {}) // and this one would be run (because this is the only active describe block) 
})

describe(() => {
   test('test 1', () => {}).      // No test will run here
   test.only('test 2', () => {}) //
})
```

#### Aliases for only():

adding an `f`. **But be careful** `ftest()` is not an alias !!!!

```
it.only()
fit()
```

```
describe.only()
fdescribe()
```

```
ftest() // WRONG ERROR !!! No such an alias SADLY!!!
```

Well, it's not sad. I personally prefer to use `only()` as it's more verbose and readable.

doc refs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testonlyname-fn-timeout
https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeonlyname-fn

**Note too:**

```
describe.only.each(table)(name, fn)
```

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#describeonlyeachtablename-fn

```
test.concurrent.only.each(table)(name, fn)
```

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testconcurrentonlyeachtablename-fn

```
test.only.failing(name, fn, timeout)
```

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testonlyfailingname-fn-timeout

## Ignore tests using config or cli

This section is for people who were searching for how to ignore full files.

### testPathIgnorePatterns

A **regex** `(regex not glob)`. Of test files to ignore if the regex match them.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring

[Github issue ref](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1815)

example:

`jest.config.ts`

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  verbose: true,
  automock: false,
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['.*/__fixtures__/.*'] // here
};

export default config;
```

Or using the cli:

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testpathignorepatternsregexarray

```bash
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=".*/__fixtures__/.*"
```

For an array (multiple regex):

There are different ways:

```bash
# one regex with or operator `|` 
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=".*/__fixtures__/.*|<rootDir>/src/someDir/"

# paranthesis with spaces
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns="\(.*/__fixtures__/.* <rootDir>/src/someDir/\)"

# using the argument multiple times
jest --testPathIgnorePatterns=".*/__fixtures__/.*" --testPathIgnorePatterns="<rootDir>/src/someDir/"
```

### testMatch

testMatch can be another way to determine what should run (just like `only()`)

It does use `globs` and **not** `regex`

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring

You can use the glob negation to ignore some files as well.

Example:

```
{
  // ... rest of the package
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/!(DISABLED.)*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "**/!(DISABLED.)?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
    ]
  }
}
```

There is the cli version as well:

https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testmatch-glob1--globn

Note that without any arguments

```bash
jest my-test #or
jest path/to/my-test.js
jest **/some/**/*.spec.*
```

That would only run the test files that are matched by the patterns.

ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#running-from-the-command-line

Comment: Adding .only (test or it) causes it to skip that test and only that one in mine.

Comment: I don't get it. https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testonlyname-fn-timeout. The api is always the same. `it.only()`  or `test.only()` will make the only() blocks run only. And not skip them ? Either im not getting what you meant ? Either there is something you are missing. may be u used skip(). or some `x`. If you can give details it would be nice. Or a link to a full example.

Answer (score 7):

### Run Only A Subset of Tests:

If you are debugging/writing/extending a test in a test suite which has many tests you just need to run the one you are working on but adding `.skip` to everyone can be painful.

So `.only` comes to the rescue. You can optionally skip others during testing using `.only` flag, it can be super useful for big suites where you need to add or debug a test.

```
describe('some amazing test suite', () => {
  test('number one', () => {
    // some testing logic
  }
  test('number two', () => {
    // some testing logic
  }
  ...
  test('number x', () => {
    // some testing logic
  }
  test.only('new test or the one needs debugging', () => {
    // Now when you run this suite only this test will run
    // so now you are free to debug or work on business logic
    // instead to wait for other tests to pass every time you run jest
    // You can remove `.only` flag once you're done!
  }
}
```

You can also add `.only` to more than one tests in a test suite or file if you want to run multiple in conjunction!

Comment: Addition: `.only` works with `it()` as well, just like `.skip`

Answer (score 0):

To ignore one step

```
const doNotIgnore=()=>{
console.log('This function will not be ignored from coverage')
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
const ignoreFunc =()=>{
console.log('This function will be ignored from coverage')
}
```

Second test will be ignore from coverage and also from the test Execution